# Is there an ActiveRecord version of Hash.Merge?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a very large set of data on which I'm doing a great deal of post-query manipulation (sorting, filtering, etc etc).  I would like do all this manipulation on an array of ActiveRecord objects that contains only the information necessary to the sorting, filtering, and paging, and then add the data necessary for display at the end.

For example, let's say I have a database with two tables: baseball_players and player_infos.  The baseball_players table contains all of the interesting stuff (stats, team, name, birthday, etc etc etc). Player_infos contains player_id, player_rank, and player_position.  I have 15000 players, and I want to find the numbers 100-150 of the best catchers of all times.  I retrieve an array of all player_infos, filter to only catchers, sort by player_rank, and then retrieve records 100-150.

What is the best way to merge the resulting player_info records with their corresponding baseball_player records?  Hash.merge would work perfectly, but I don't want to convert these objects to Hashes.  Does ActiveRecord support something similar?

Note that I have a restriction where I cannot simply query the data using SQL - I have to manually sort and filter an object containing all 15000 player_info records.

Comment: Why do you not want to convert the objects to hashes? Is it just to retain access to properties via named methods (`player.name`) instead of hash key (`player[:name]`)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for [`ActiveRecord::Base#update`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000340).

Comment: I don't want to do anything that affects the data in the database - I just want to merge one object with another based on a primary key, and display the data from both objects.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that at all. Instead of 100-150 records, can you update your question with an example showing three records? Do you have three player_info records, but 15,000 baseball_player records, and you need to find the single associated baseball_player record for each player_info record? And then you want to merge those two ActiveRecord objects into some new object that has the properties of both models exposed as methods?